# Beamer - make itemize (and space occupied) disappear

Tags: latex, overlay, space, beamer

So I have two itemize's on one slide and a graphic underneath them both:

```
\onslide<1>{
    \begin{itemize}
      ...
    \end{itemize}
}

\onslide<2>{
    \begin{itemize}
      ...
    \end{itemize}
}

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{abc.eps}
```

So what I want is for the first itemize to be visible on the first slide, and the second itemize to be invisible **and not occupy any space**.  Similarly, when I go to the next slide, I want the first itemize to go invisible **and not occupy any space** while showing the second itemize.  I want the graphic to be visible and stay in the same place on both slides.

Is this possible?

Comment: Okay, I think I've got half of it: I'm now using \only<n> instead of \onslide<n>.  Now I've just got to figure out how to make the graphic stay at a fixed position.

Comment: Add a \vspace{1cm} inside the \only<n>{} which is smaller, with the size (1cm inside the {})adjusted to make the two \onslide be of the same size. I hope it is not too late for you  :)  If you want more explanation let me know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use \alt or \temporal:

`\alt<n>{at n}{not at n}` for two alternatives.

`\temporal<n>{before}{at n}{after}` for three alternatives.

More information at http://saikat.guha.cc/ref/beamer_guide.pdf

Answer (score 14):

One can simply combine both itemizations in a single one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}   

\begin{itemize}
    \item<only@1> item on first slide
    \item<only@1> more item on first slide
    \item<only@2> item on second slide
    \item<only@2> more item on second slide 
\end{itemize}

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```